# movement of the object, without interference from the any operation system?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a test code for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        bri {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
        }
        .dirt {
            background-color:brown;
        }
        .gracz {
            background-color:red
        }
    </style>
    <script >
        function makeLevel() {
            width = 30
            heigth = 30

            var bricks = document.getElementById('bricks')
            bricks.style.width = 20 * heigth + 'px'
            bricks.style.height = 20 * width + 'px'
            bricks.innerHTML = ''

            for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < heigth; j++) {
                    var bri = document.createElement("bri");
                    bricks.appendChild(bri)
                    bri.style.top = i * 20 + "px"
                    bri.style.left = j * 20 + "px"
                    bri.id = i + "_" + j
                    bri.className = 'dirt'
                }
            }
            pos_player_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * width)
            pos_player_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * heigth)
            bri = document.getElementById(pos_player_x + '_' + pos_player_y);
            bri.className = 'gracz'
        }

        function moving(event) {
            var key = event.which
            //87 - w , 83 -s, 65 -a, 68 - d
            switch (key) {
                case 87:
                    var new_x = pos_player_x - 1;
                    var new_y = pos_player_y - 0;
                    break;
                case 83:
                    var new_x = pos_player_x + 1;
                    var new_y = pos_player_y - 0;
                    break;
                case 65:
                    var new_x = pos_player_x - 0;
                    var new_y = pos_player_y - 1;
                    break;
                case 68:
                    var new_x = pos_player_x - 0;
                    var new_y = pos_player_y + 1;
                    break;
            }
            var new_pos = document.getElementById(new_x + '_' + new_y)
            var old_pos = document.getElementById(pos_player_x + '_' + pos_player_y)
            if (new_pos != null) {
                new_pos.className = 'gracz';
                old_pos.className = 'clean';
                pos_player_y = new_y;
                pos_player_x = new_x;
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="makeLevel()" onkeydown="moving(event)">                
            <div id="game">
                <div id="bricks" draggable="false"></div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And we need to focus on the function called "moving".
If we pressed and hold one of the button 'WASD' our player will follow this direction. But, for the first second he moved once and after this they will repeat until he reach one of the wall.

And here is the question. 
How to remove this little pause if we hold one of this button?

This is my first post, so sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Im trying to realize what pause youre talking about... seems to be working fine in my opinion;

Comment: Yes, if you press the key once this work fine. But hold it for a moment. First move is ok too, but there is a little pause, and the object keep moving.

Comment: oh you mean it moves kinda like in steps, not in a soft fluid way? i see it now.

Comment: Check the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487951/image-stops-for-a-second-while-switching-arrow-keys), it will also help you with other problems you may have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your movement is tied to the number of keypresses received. This is problematic not only because of the OS issue you perceive (i.e. how soon it'll start sending the repeated key), but also because it allows faster movement if someone were to press the key faster ("spamming") than the base repeating speed of a held down button.

Instead, your game should have an internal 'tick', which quantizes movement. When keys are pressed and released, you propagate those changes to an internal variable, and every time your game decides it's time to move, move based on the current state of this variable. This will mean that no matter whether someone is holding down the key or spamming, regardless of the speed with which the OS is sending the repeat signals, the block will move exactly as fast as your game allows.

EDIT: Here's an adjusted version of your code. Note the newly introduced `startGameLoop` function, and how I use the `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` events. In this version, the snake moves at a steady pace while a key is pressed, and doesn't move after it has been released.

HTML: `<body onload="makeLevel()" onkeydown="registerKey(event)" onkeyup="releaseKey()">`

Javascript:

```
    var currentlyPressedKey;

    function makeLevel() {
        width = 30
        heigth = 30

        var bricks = document.getElementById('bricks')
        bricks.style.width = 20 * heigth + 'px'
        bricks.style.height = 20 * width + 'px'
        bricks.innerHTML = ''

        for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < heigth; j++) {
                var bri = document.createElement("bri");
                bricks.appendChild(bri)
                bri.style.top = i * 20 + "px"
                bri.style.left = j * 20 + "px"
                bri.id = i + "_" + j
                bri.className = 'dirt'
            }
        }
        pos_player_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * width)
        pos_player_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * heigth)
        bri = document.getElementById(pos_player_x + '_' + pos_player_y);
        bri.className = 'gracz';
        startGameLoop();
    }

    function startGameLoop(){
      setInterval(move,250);
    }

    function registerKey(event){
      currentlyPressedKey = event.which;
    }

    function releaseKey(){
      currentlyPressedKey = null;
    }

    function move() {
        var key = currentlyPressedKey;
        //87 - w , 83 -s, 65 -a, 68 - d
        switch (key) {
            case 87:
                var new_x = pos_player_x - 1;
                var new_y = pos_player_y - 0;
                break;
            case 83:
                var new_x = pos_player_x + 1;
                var new_y = pos_player_y - 0;
                break;
            case 65:
                var new_x = pos_player_x - 0;
                var new_y = pos_player_y - 1;
                break;
            case 68:
                var new_x = pos_player_x - 0;
                var new_y = pos_player_y + 1;
                break;
        }
        var new_pos = document.getElementById(new_x + '_' + new_y)
        var old_pos = document.getElementById(pos_player_x + '_' + pos_player_y)
        if (new_pos != null) {
            new_pos.className = 'gracz';
            old_pos.className = 'clean';
            pos_player_y = new_y;
            pos_player_x = new_x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, this works. But still there is similar issue. When i change keys very fast  my object stays for a little moment and then moves. I don't want to have that delay.

Comment: Well ultimately you will have to tailor this code to your exact needs. For example, if you remove the `releaseKey` function, you get a classical snake-game-like behaviour. If you want immediate movement on keypresses, you can implement a system where you check for `keyup` events to determine whether a key is repeated by the user or the OS -- but as I outlined in my opening paragraph, I don't think that's a good approach.

Comment: @ProPaniusz: when you release any key after pressing another one, the code stops the player, until `keydown` is re-send, and that's the reason of the delay you're experiencing. One possible solution is to stop the player only when no keys are pressed. The simplest way of accomplishing this I can image is to use `Set` to keep track of pressed keys (add keycode on `keydown`, remove on `keyup`), and only stop the player if the set is empty.